# Load items into a select menu using $.load

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to load a list into a select menu using the following jquery code:

```
$('select name=class[0][location_id]').load('/locations/json');
```

However, i'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: select name=class[0][location_id]
```

The HTML code looks like this:

```
<select class="inp" name="class[0][location_id]"></select>
```

Does anyone have the correct syntax?

Comment: please tell what you want to do. We are not mind readers...

Comment: Are you trying to select the select box by name attribute?

Comment: Like the title says, trying to load a list of options into a select menu...

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: HTML aded @guest271314

Answer (score 0):

See [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```js
var selected  = $("select[name='class[0][location_id]']");
console.log(selected);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="inp" name="class[0][location_id]"></select>
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work either.  I have just changed my post above to include the HTML in the page.

Comment: This doesn't throw any errors.  However my select box doesn't get populated.  Maybe because the select box is generated dynamically?

Comment: _"However my select box doesn't get populated. Maybe because the select box is generated dynamically?"_ Can create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?  What is response from `'/locations/json'`  ? What is expected result ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to figure out the expected name, then use that in the right selector.

`var nameValue = class[myNameIncrement2][location_id];
$('select[name='+nameValue+']').load('/locations/json');`

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$('select[name="class[0][location_id]"]').load('/locations/json');
```